# How limit CPU/Ram on a system service on nixos?

Tags: systemd, nixos, limit

My metabase service is eating all the [resources on my machine](https://github.com/metabase/metabase/issues/12060), and while found a solution I need a way to limit the usage the resources.

How can I configure it on nixos?

```
❯ nixos-version
22.05.2123.ede02b4ccb1 (Quokka)
```

My service is configured:

```
  systemd.services.metabase = {
    description = "Metabase server";
    wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
    wants = [ "postgresql.service" "nginx.service" ];
    after = [ "network.target" "postgresql.service" ];
    environment = {
      JAVA_OPTS = "-Dc3p0.maxPoolSize=2 -Xms128m -Xmx1024m";
      MB_DB_TYPE = "postgres";
      MB_DB_DBNAME="metabase";
      MB_DB_HOST="127.0.0.1";
      MB_DB_PORT="5432";
      MB_DB_USER="postgres";
      MB_PLUGINS_DIR = "/var/lib/metabase";
      MB_JETTY_HOST = "127.0.0.1";
      MB_JETTY_PORT = "3000";
    };

    serviceConfig = {
      DynamicUser = true;
      StateDirectory = "/var/lib/metabase";
      ExecStart = "${pkgs.metabase}/bin/metabase";
      RuntimeMaxSec = 86400;
      Restart = "always";
      RestartSec = 1;
    };
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use systemd's [resource control options](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) in `serviceConfig`.